# How to mesure the latency of thread switching

Tags: performance, testing, cpu-usage, multithreading

I'm learning how to test the performance of a unix-like system.

I've found a tool to measure the context switching time: http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lat_ctx.8.html

Now I want to know if it is possible to measure the latency of thread switching? Is there some way or some tool to do so?

I think it is different from the context switching. As my understanding, the context switching is about the switching of processes, whereas threads exists in a process, they also need to do some switching job to get the opportunity of executing.